# hdfs command: ls not find files hdfs namespace after hadoop federation implement

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

After implementing hadoop federation when I give bellow command its works fine.

```
> hdfs dfs -ls  /

-r-xr-xr-x   - hdfs hadoop          0 2016-11-02 00:13 /home    
-r-xr-xr-x   - hdfs hadoop          0 2016-11-02 00:13 /projects    
-r-xr-xr-x   - hdfs hadoop          0 2016-11-02 00:13 /user
```

But when I give bellow command

```
> hdfs dfs -ls  /home
ls: `/home': No such file or directory
```

What is the reason. If any one help me it will be better for me.

Answer (score 0):

The particular user doesn't have access to /home

Try with sudo or change permission of /home path